# get stack strace in global error handler

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3, air

In my adobe AIR application I have registered a global error handler. While debugging I get stack trace of all errors and error events, but in release mode stack trace is not available unless you put debug file in APP_DIR/META-INF/AIR folder.

I have checked Adobe Jira, there is a feature request to allow getting stack trace in flash player. I am asking if there is any workaround for this? I tried placing debug file programatically in application but that doesn't work in case user doesn't have rights on Installation folder.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure, as of now, there is no workaround to get a stack trace in the global error handler.